# Is a question about how to mill metals in a specific situation on topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

I need to better understand metal milling, specifically speeds and feeds, and don't know where to start.

I have a specific project where I need to machine 5/8" diameter slots into an aluminum block using a manual milling machine.

Would a question about speeds and feeds for this specific situation be on topic?

Answer (score 8):

I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be. Feed rate and tool speed given material, feature size, and required finish/tolerance are pretty fundamental concepts of manufacturing engineering, so it's not out-of scope. Just make sure you have done some searching around for existing information. I'm willing to bet that you'll be able to find some stuff about CNC mills, but if there's not readily available info on manual tools, ask away.